# karma.js not returning any results following basic "karma init" setup

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm following the "Introduction to Karma" tutorial by egghead.io found here https://egghead.io/lessons/unit-testing-introduction-to-karma , and followed the following (on Windows):

```
> npm install --g karma-cli
> npm install karma karma-jasmine karma-chrome-launcher --save-dev
karma init
```

Followed default configuration on initial karma configuration, and then created a test.spec.js file in current folder with the following code:

```
describe('Test', function() {
    it('It should be true', function() { expect(true).toBe(true); });
});
```

Lastly, I added such file to the karma.conf.js file like so:

```
files: [
      'test.spec.js'
    ],
```

However, upon running

```
karma start karma.conf.js
```

I get nothing but a:

```
25 11 2015 16:35:35.551:INFO [karma]: Karma v0.13.15 server started at http://localhost:9876/
```

Why don't any tests execute? Also, opening that localhost url (it's the same as setting browsers to ['chrome'] in karma.conf.js) just shows that karma is running and that chrome is idle, but no test results are returned.

edit: Added karma.conf.js

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Wed Nov 25 2015 16:19:43 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time (Mexico))

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      '*spec.js'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: false,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: [],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultanous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

edit2: Added package.json

```
{
  "name": "karma-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start karma.conf.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "jasmine-core": "^2.3.4",
    "karma": "^0.13.15",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.6"
  }
}
```

edit3: **Found a solution**. Check my own reply

Comment: Can you share `karma.conf.js`?

Comment: done, added that and package.json

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199900/karma-test-runner-not-running-any-tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, or sort of. It seems like I had to press the big "DEBUG" button on the localhost:9876 url, open the chrome console and find the results there. That was highly confusing, and I wish the Karma docs told me that. Now we just need a way to display the results in the windows console

**EDIT**

Fixed it...I'm amazed at how this could fix it. Either way, we finally got the right output by setting autoWatch to true (it was false) in karma.conf.js AND opening http://localhost:9876. I'm still confused that I tought karma used headless tests that didn't require a browser, but I'll look into that later. I'm guessing this is to make debugging easier.

Comment: You added the `browsers : ['Chrome']` in your Karma config file?

Comment: No, I just opened http://localhost:9876 and I got the karma UI, albeit setting ['Chrome'] could have made that faster. We want to get the results in the node console over a browser since we plan to use this with Jenkins

Comment: Karma CAN use a headless browser, it's called PhantomJS or PhantomJS2 and you can install either local to your project with `npm install --save-dev karma-phantomjs-launcher` or `npm install --save-dev karma-phantomjs2-launcher`.  Then simply add it: `browsers: ['PhantomJS']` or `browsers: ['PhantomJS2']`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `browsers : ['Chrome']` for the Karma run your test automatically.

If you don't do this, you'll need to open this in your browser: http://localhost:9876/ to  capture a browser open.

Comment: That's the same as navigating to that url manually on a browser (I read the documentation), which we did (I included that on the question description). But it still didn't show the results we wanted. Found an answer which sorta explains it, check my own reply